# Issue floating elements inside position:fixed div

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to set up a form inside a jquery popup, I would like to give each  element a width to make input fields look nice, all in the same column. But it doesn't work, I think it is because they are inside a position fixed div. How could i solve it?

here's the HTML code:

```
<div id="toPopup">
<div class="close"></div>
<div class="popup_content">
    <form>
        <ul>
            <li><label>Conductor<label><input type=text></li>
            <li><label>Entrega<label><input type=text></li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#backgroundPopup {
z-index:1;
position: fixed;
height:100%;
width:100%;
background:#000000;
top:0px;
left:0px;
display:none;
}
#toPopup {
display:none;
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 3px solid #F5F5DC;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -303px;
position: fixed;
top: 20%;
width: 600px;
z-index: 2;
}

div.close {
background: url("../img/closebox.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
cursor: pointer;
height: 30px;
position: absolute;
right: -27px;
top: -24px;
width: 30px;
}

div.popup_content {
padding: 8px 20px;
}
/* qui personalizzo il form interno al popup*/

div.popup_content form label{
font-size:0.8rem;
font-weight:bold;
margin-bottom:4px;
padding-left:10px;
height:32px;
line-height:32px;
display:block;
width:400px;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Your label tag issn't closed. Pls validate your code and try again. After that please create a fiddle. That makes working out the problem easier.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem! I really apologize for the stupid question